# Word/phrase that means "secondary" without implying a lack of importance

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Trying to think of a word or short phrase to describe something as being secondary but without implying that it is unimportant.

Comment: Words like *supporting* and *ancillary* and the like can describe necessary members, but relative importance will always be in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: How do you intend to use this word?  *Secondary* does not imply *unimportant*, just *not as important as the primary*.

Comment: Also, please see http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info for information on how to ask a good single-word-request question.

Comment: *In a restaurant, the appearance of the food is next in importance to its taste and quality*.

Comment: One thing to consider is the context you set up: if you imply that the first item you mention is the most important you'll get bogged down trying to justify why the second isn't secondary. If instead you start out by saying there are "2 key factors" (or something like that) of which you'll address the "simpler (but not the more important)" first you'll have no trouble getting your point across.

Answer (score 1):

*accompanying*:

http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/accompanying

*ancillary*:

http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/ancillary

*additional*:

http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/additional

Comment: Judging by the part of speech, I imagine you meant “additional”.

Comment: In that case, you should edit your post with the correction.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right word, why look further...

> "Secondary” without implying a lack of importance would be
>   context/situation dependent.

Since second is a form of the number two, Secondary implies - *must be done next.*

> Something secondary is second most important.

However, when you say- "This is my target. Everything else is secondary." **It can also refer to  things that are not important at all.**