# Name for a new second team working on the same project without implying it is a secondary?

Tags: single-word-requests

Similar to [Word/phrase that means "secondary" without implying a lack of importance](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/225521) but with the particular application of naming a team.

As a concrete example we have a team working on 'Widget' and they are the 'Widget Team', now we have a second team working on Widget. We could call them 'Widget Team B' or 'Widget Team 2' but these imply that they are secondary to the main team. Star Trek did it with 'Next Generation' but obviously this is a bit overblown (although I am open to ideas!)

Is there a word/phrase or way to refer to them that implies that they are equivelent but different?

Comment: Are the teams working alongside each other? What distinguishes one team from the other (other than just personnel)?

Comment: Let them name themselves.  They could be Team Felix and Team Oscar or whatever they choose.

Comment: “Team B” has been used in this sense—as a second group to challenge the work of an established group—in the CIA of the US government, possibly other agencies.

Comment: Team a and Team _α_ (use a suitable font for lower-case alpha. Getting on for _∝_).

Comment: You could refer to them inclusively as *"the rest of the team"* implying they had not arrived yet or were working elsewhere.

Comment: To expand on what @KillingTime wrote - are tasks going to be assigned at random to each team, or will each one have an area of focus?  If it's the latter, then use the area of focus to distinguish them: the Widget Electronics Team and the Widget Mechanical Team, for example. We're wandering pretty far from a question about English, though.

Comment: Assuming they're doing the same work, but each team is doing half of it, and you can't divide by location or anything like that. If you want to give numbers or letters, you can tell them the identifiers were assigned randomly. Otherwise you're left with giving them completely meaningless names like after different colours or animals. Colours might be a good choice, but these things can provoke stupid arguments (it's often the low-stakes, trivial things that cause endless debate).

Comment: *Hogan’s Heroes* used Papa Bear, Mama Bear, and Goldilocks. English doesn’t really constrain the choice of names.

Comment: Call them **Team Apple** and **Team Orange**. There’s an old expression about “comparing apples with oranges”.

Answer (score 1):

If there are two teams both working the same problem and, regardless of whether they started at the same time or at different times, neither has priority over the other but each is equal, you would avoid using the word "second" by saying something like, "We now have *two teams* independently working the problem."

To name those teams, you would give them names that don't suggest any kind of ranking or order, so you would *not* call them *Team One* and *Team Two* or *Team A* and *Team B*, for example, but would call them by some distinguishing factor free of ranking connotation, like if one team is working in New York and the other in Los Angeles, you might call them the *New York Team* and the *L.A. Team*; if one is led by Susan Jones and the other is led by Mike Smith, you might call them *Team Jones* and *Team Smith*; or failing to come up with any such distinguisher, you could call them something like *Team Apple* and *Team Orange*.

***EXAMPLE:***

An example is found in the Manhattan Project.

Initially, there was just the Manhattan Project, one large team of scientists during World War II working the fission problem, the problem of starting a nuclear chain reaction in bomb-form. Then some scientists on the Manhattan Project came up with a second proposal that completely deviated from the design and direction the team had been pursuing until then. That's when a second team was started.

From that point on, the original team of scientists on the Manhattan Project became two separate teams, an original team pursuing the original design and direction of development and a new team pursuing the newly proposed design and direction of development, neither subordinate or secondary to the other, even though one clearly started later than the other.

Since the Manhattan Project had split into two teams, leadership needed to name the two teams in order to differentiate them and the separate work they were doing for discussions among themselves and with military brass, but leadership wanted to avoid names that appeared to rank one team above the other in priority and authority because of potential for contention between the teams where one maybe would come to be considered over the other, having higher priority to resources and more or less in charge such that the other would be perceived to be subordinate.

With that in mind and because the proposed design for one was big and round and the proposed design for the other was long and skinny, Robert Oppenheimmer, leader of the Manhattan Project, aptly codenamed one team *Fat Man* and the other team *Thin Man*— as opposed to *Team One* and *Team Two*, *Team A* and *Team B*, or anything else that might suggest order or rank. Each ended up solving the problem nearly at the same time, albeit in completely different ways, and each of their designs ended up being used.